# What is the computational complexity for diagonalizing covariance matrix

Tags: diagonalization

I am considering using an algorithm called Covariance Matrix Adaptation Evolution Strategy (CMA-ES) for global optimization. Part of the algorithm involves taking a square root of a covariance matrix, which requires that the matrix be diagonalized. Since the covariance matrix will be rather large $(N\ge100)$ I am concerned about the computational cost of this square root step. What is the computational complexity for diagonalizing a covariance matrix? Or is there anyway of computing the square root of a matrix without diagonalizing?

Answer (score 4):

Probably you should take realization of Singular Value Decomposition algorithm, it's complexity is $O(N^3)$.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

You may find many details in this paper: [PERFORMANCE AND ACCURACY OF LAPACK’S SYMMETRIC
TRIDIAGONAL EIGENSOLVERS](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn183.pdf). I remember that the QR algorithm is $3bn^3 + O(n^2)$ while the Divide and Conquer algorithm is $O(n^3)$ in the worst case.

Do you need to do this many times? Otherwise a symmetric 1000x1000 matrix should be a matter of a second according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713878/how-expensive-is-it-to-compute-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix).

Unfortunately, I am unaware of an other method to take the square root.